# In Vim, why is :move randomly corrupting my folds?

Tags: vim, folding

I have a small mapping for <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd> that moves text up and down one line. I decided that these mapping should be made "fold aware" so that moving text up one line will move it *past a closed fold*. But when I play around with these mappings vim will corrupt my folds.

**The mappings:**
The mappings work by calling the `:move` function.  The argument to `:move` is the absolute line number below which the text should be moved.

```
nnoremap <A-Down> :call MoveDown_n()<CR>
nnoremap <A-Up> :call MoveUp_n()<CR>

function! MoveUp_n() range
let pos = getpos(".")
normal k
let line_pos = line(".") - 1
call setpos(".", pos)
execute "m".line_pos
endfunction

function! MoveDown_n() range
let pos = getpos(".")
normal jj
let line_pos = line(".") - 1
call setpos(".", pos)
execute "m".line_pos
endfunction
```

**Test File:**

```
 vim: foldmethod=marker



fold A {{{
some
  text
     here
}}}
fold B {{{
some
  text
     here
}}}
fold C {{{
some
  text
     here
}}}
fold D {{{
some
  text
     here
}}}
```

**The Problem:**
When I load the test file (with all folds closed) and place the cursor on one of the folds then at first the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd> keys seem to move the fold like one expects. But if you keep moving the folds past one another enough then:

1. Folds start becoming unexpanded ("corrupted") for no apparent reason.
2. You can't close these folds, because vim cannot detect that there is a fold there anymore.
3. Saving and re-editing the file (`:e`) seems to fix the folds.

Sometimes it will happen with the first movement, and sometimes not.  I've even had test cases where folds boundaries would be detected incorrectly instead of not being detected at all.  For example, a fold that Vim thinks starts with the intermediate line `text`.

--- Edit ---
**More testing:**
Moving fold A seems to cause most of the problems.  If you don't touch fold A, I  think you can move folds B, C, and D around without encountering a problem.

If you move fold A up twice (see note-1) it will corrupt folds B, C, and D.  If you move fold A down once (see note-2) it will corrupt fold B.

(note-1) put cursor on fold A (line 5), then either do `:move3`, `:move2` or do `:move-2`, then `kj`, then `:move-2`.
(note-2) put the cursor on fold A (line 5) then do `:move14`

Something I noticed is that after any `:move` operation, the cursor is placed at the first column of the last line of the fold.  But performing the command `:move-2` twice on the fold A will corrupt folds B, C, and D even if you were to reset the cursor to the first line of fold A before performing the second `:move-2` command.

If it matters: using gvim 7.3 on windows

Comment: I'm not sure what your script is trying to do. `m` only move one line but you are trying to move multiple line at the same time (the all fold should move, not only the 'current' line)

Comment: When the cursor is positioned on a closed fold, vim will operate on all lines of the fold for most commands.

Comment: @Ein I played around with this a little. Looks like a Vim bug to me. I recommend stripping down your example as much as possible and filing a bug report on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev).

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete the whole line and paste it and that works out of the box (and it's fold aware)

```
nnoremap <a-down> ddp
nnoremap <a-up> ddkP
```

Also the up version doesn't work at the bottom of the file.

Comment: This is a workaround for what I was trying to do (although the mapping should be for `<a-down>`), but it doesn't explain what's going terribly wrong with `:move`.  Thanks for spotting the error at the bottom of the file (the down version is the problem).